# Passbook Pass Error ./signpass: Permission denied

Tags: ios, signing, wallet

When signing my Passbook pass for Apple Wallet in the console I am getting the above error, I have validated my JSON and double-checked my identifiers. Has anyone else experienced or trouble-shot this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:**

Right click on file signpass -> click "Show Original"
   You will get the original file. use that "File path" to create the passes.

**Step 2**

Check Lollipop.pass file extension in getInfo. (Sometimes it is Lollipop.pass.raw)

**Step 3**

.(File path)/signpass -p Lollipop.pass

**Step 4**

Then press enter

**OUTPUT**

Lollipop.pkpass file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you find out the log of that pass error for?

Try to use iOS Simulator to open the pass, just drop your pass into the simulator, then: `iOS Simulator > Menu Bar > Debug > Open System Log`, the log will provide the reason(s) of error in most of the case.

if you still cannot find out the problem, you may provide your pass in here.

Answer (score 0):

./signpass refers to the executable that appears after you build a project.

Go to XCode -> File -> Project (Workspace) Settings. In the Per-User Workspace Settings change the location of the Derived Data to your project's root directory. Build the project again and open the root directory in Finder. Open the signpass-gaggexlhfdlcagcckqzwcfpxoqek -> Build -> Products -> Debug. You'll find the executable `signpass` there. Move it to a different directory (e.g. Documents) and move the Folder.pass there. After that  `./signpass -p Folder.pass` should work.

Comment: when i build the signpass project (after following your steps), i cannot find the executable. Any suggestiojs

Comment: After you move the executable you are not able to build the project. Instead you should run it from the terminal using command ./signpass -p Folder.pass